# Selecting an img element, without an id, stacked in multiple div's

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an img, that does not have an id and is stacked something like this:

```
<div class = "someclass">
  <div>
   <div>
     <img>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the following jQuery selector to get the result :

```
$('.someclass div div img')
```

did not work, I also tried

```
$('.someclass').children('img')
```

that did not work either, and then I tried this ridiculous selector:

```
$('.someclass').children('div').children('div').children('img') ;
```

and that offcourse did not work.

How do I select that elusive img element, and where can I read up more in detail?

Comment: jQuery's `children()` only looks at immediate descendants, so `$('.someclass').children('img')` will not find anything. All of the other selectors you posted should work though, as well as `$('.someclass').find('img')`, which will traverse through every descendant to find an `img`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using jQuery's [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$(".someclass").find("img");
```

Comment: Using `find` is less efficient than using a single selector.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the only image element in that div, then you can just look for the `img` element somewhere in the element with that class:

```
var image = $('.someclass img');
```

Comment: Using find() is a lot more efficient.

Comment: @Cofey: You are mistaken. Using `find` means that you run two selectors instead of one.

Comment: @guffa, as I have clearly stated in my question, it isn't that one image element in the div but rather an img within multiple divs that are all inside .someclass div

Comment: @ParijatKalia: The selector find all `img` elements that are somewhere inside any element with the class `someclass`, no matter how deeply nested.

Comment: @Cofey: I tested in Firefox, IE, Chrome and Opera, and using `find` is about 50% slower everywhere. http://jsfiddle.net/cbSap/

Comment: @Guffa According to this [fairly robust test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel/29), it would appear that `.find()` actually performs more efficiently.

Comment: @RubenInfante: Actually it shows the exact opposite of what you say.

Comment: @RubenInfante: Yes, the "cascade" method is considerably faster than the "select and find" method. For example in Firefox; 10220 ops/s compared to 2163. That is about 4.7 times faster.

Comment: @Guffa You are correct, I was looking at the node context method which assumes you have already extracted the node. Thanks for pointing that out. +1

Answer (score -2):

You can use children selector

```
$('.someclass').children(0).children(0).children(0);
```

Comment: This code will break if any elements are added or removed from the DOM.

Comment: true but he can use it if he doesn't change the structure